# A group of two elements to 'add' to my text area don't align with the page

Tags: css, sass

So I've got an "input group" for a textarea and a simple div containing a character count.

Here is what it looks like, but it shouldn't be that long as i set a min/max width and using `position: absolute` messes it all up.

[image: Textarea]

Here is the code that I'm  using for it:

```
textarea {
    min-width: 120px;
    min-height: 90px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(#E0E0E0, .50), 0 -1px 1px #FFF, 0 1px 0 #FFF;

    @include transition(all .2s ease-in-out);

    @include placeholder {
        font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    }
}
textarea:focus {
    border: 1px solid lighten(#3498db, 10);

    @include box-shadow(0px, 0px, 6px, rgba(lighten(#3498db, 10), .5), false);
}
.textarea-group {
    //position: absolute; //FIX?
    min-width: 120px;
    min-height: 90px;

    textarea[limit] {
        display: block;
        resize: none;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0; border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .chars {
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 8px 10px;
        background: #FAFAFA;
        color: #999;
        font-size: 11px;
        border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 2px; border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, min-width and min-height will only be helpful if you don't want the textarea to be any less than the numbers that you specified when browsers get resized. what you need is max-width and max-height.

Second of all, the best practice of limiting height and weight is by adding the following attributes to your textarea:

```
rows="number" cols="number"
```

for example:

```
<textarea placeholder="some text" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: Yes but I'm adding the constraints for both parts of it so i can show the counter like that as well. So in this case, what would I do to align them properly, so that the container group can be modified to shift both elements

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, but let me try. You have a text area and a word count placed below it. You want to constrain the width of both and keep them well-aligned. First, you don't have max-width in your code, and since you specified display:block css will assume that you want it to take the full width. If you want to align both you can either give exact numbers: width: 120px. or put them in a div and center them horizontally this way they will resize with browser, check it out here: http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html